# Is there any performance difference between GTX 580 and GTX 580M

Tags: laptop, graphics, desktop-computer

I know that the M versions are built for laptops but let's make this as an example:

```
Laptop has:  i7 - 4GB RAM - GTX580  (3gb dedicated)
Desktop has: i7 - 4gb RAM - GTX580M (3gb dedicated)
```

If i run a game like GTA IV, will there be performance differences between the laptop and the desktop having them at the same specs at everything except the graphics card version?

Like how the graphics look, the anti aliasing quality, and the FPS?

Answer (score 0):

The GTX 580M is slower than the GTX 580.  They represent the most advanced graphics available from NVIDIA for their respective platforms and are both capable of running many games at high settings at reasonably high resolutions, but this performance difference will be noticeable on the most demanding games.  As an example, for a given resolution, if the desktop version can run Crysis at Very High, the mobile version may only be playable at High or perhaps Medium.  Note that both GPUs are SLI capable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a major performance difference. The 580M is compared in reviews to the 560 or 560ti. The following link is a reputable source with an objective overview of the 580M. At the bottom of the page you will find benchmark results you can directly compare with results from the 580.

http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-580M.56636.0.html